# Boxes do not fit for mobile devices

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive

I have an issue. When I look at my welcome page ( which contains two simple boxes, which are actually just a JPG picture ) from a mobile device, the boxes won't resize so they can match the phone size. They Look something like this on desktop:

[Desktop view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2knof.jpg)

[Mobile View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GVrd.jpg)

**HTML**:

```
<div class="l-sec col-xs-2 col-xs-8 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
    <img class="box" src="images/ex.jpg"> 
    <img class="box" src="images/ex.jpg"> 
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url(images/background.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center; 
}


.box {
    margin: 40px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 20px 0px #2b2b2b;
    transition: box-shadow 0.3s ease-in-out; 
}
```

Could anyone tell me how to make those boxes fit and make them smaller for mobiles only ? I would be forever in your debt :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to reformat your page for a mobile device, you need to use the meta tag `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` in your `head`, and media-queries in your CSS. See [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp) for an excellent tutorial on reformatting your page to fit a mobile device.